Perfect interpolation (sinc) of Fourier spectrum equivalent to zero-padding time domain
I need to up-sample a 2D Fourier spectrum, this can be done by zero padding the image before the FFT. But in my particular case I cannot perform an FFT or IFFT, the interpolation must be performed in the Fourier domain.
Here, to make visualization easier, I will present only the 1D case.
I use Python and the PyTorch library to perform the computation, but almost everything can be converted name for name to NumPy.
import torch
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from torch.nn import functional as F

# Parameters
Ts: float = 2.0  # Sampling period
NUM_POINTS: int = 10
FACTOR: int = 16  # Factor by which to up-sample (new signal will have NUM_POINTS*FACTOR samples)

def func(time: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    """Generate a 1D signal and its spectrum"""
    return 5*torch.sin(time) + 3*torch.cos(time*2) + time * 0.5

# Sampling times
original_t = torch.arange(start=0, end=NUM_POINTS*Ts, step=Ts, dtype=torch.float)
# Time domain signal
original_signal = func(original_t)
# Fourier spectrum of said signal
original_spectrum = torch.fft.fftshift(torch.fft.fft(original_signal))

# Plotting
plt.plot(original_t, original_spectrum.abs(), marker="o", label="Original")
plt.legend()
plt.title("Original Spectrum of 1D signal")
plt.show()


FFT based interpolation
padding: int = (NUM_POINTS*FACTOR - NUM_POINTS) // 2
old_signal_padded = F.pad(original_signal, (padding,padding), mode="constant", value=0)

interpolated_spectrum = torch.fft.fftshift(torch.fft.fft(old_signal_padded))

# Generate interpolation times
interpolated_t = torch.arange(start=0, end=NUM_POINTS*Ts, step=Ts/FACTOR, dtype=torch.float)

# Plotting
plt.plot(interpolated_t, interpolated_spectrum.abs(), marker="x", label="Up-sampled")
plt.plot(original_t, original_spectrum.abs(), marker="o", label="Original")
plt.legend()
plt.title("Magnitude of original and interpolated spectrum (using zero-padding + FFT)")
plt.show()


The zero-padding theorem states that zero-padding the spatial domain is equivalent to a convolution of the Fourier spectrum with an infinite sinc (sinus cardinal) kernel. But I cannot obtain the same result, what is the correct way to do it?
Here is a visualization of the sinc interpolation process
I tried:
Sinc interpolation
# Generate interpolation times
interpolated_t = torch.arange(start=0, end=NUM_POINTS*Ts, step=Ts/FACTOR, dtype=torch.float)

# Compute the differences for sinc interpolation
sinc_matrix = interpolated_t.unsqueeze(1) - original_t.unsqueeze(0)
sinc_matrix /= Ts
sinc_matrix.sinc_()

# Perform the interpolation
interpolated_spectrum = torch.matmul(sinc_matrix.to(original_spectrum.dtype), original_spectrum)

# Plotting
plt.plot(interpolated_t, interpolated_spectrum.abs(), marker="x", label="Up-sampled")
plt.plot(original_t, original_spectrum.abs(), marker="o", label="Original")
plt.legend()
plt.title("Magnitude of original and interpolated spectrum (sinc interpolation)")
plt.show()


This code, despite providing an up-sampling of the signal does not fit my needs because it does not provide the same result  as zero-padding in the time domain before the FFT (which I cannot do).
How do I obtain the same result?
Edit
For context, I am doing research inspired by this paper, more specifically the section 3.2 where they interpolate a Fourier CNN kernel and then perform back-propagation on it.
The reason I cannot use bi-linear interpolation or other methods than sinc interpolation is because I need the interpolation of the Fourier spectrum to be equal to an IFFT followed by zero-padding followed by an FFT (but without doing all that for efficiency reasons) (proof on Standford website).
For more context, the reason I cannot perform the interpolation of my Fourier spectrum by doing an IFFT followed by an FFT is because I am working on fMRI data, and MRIs samples data in the Fourier domain (commonly called k-space), but to convert the k-space to a spatial domain image it is not just a simple IFFT, the reconstruction process is very time consuming.

It's an XY problem. Why do you do a sinc interpolation on the magnitudes of DFT? It's not meaningful. Why not just do a bilinear or cubic interpolation on them? Also keep in mind that you lost the phase information by using only the magnitudes.

I edited the question to include context as to why I want to perform sinc interpolation and not another method. And yes, I realize I only plotted the magnitude of the interpolated spectrum so phase information may also be wrongly interpolated.
But still, magnitude is wrongly interpolated too so I will try to fix that first.

You could take a look at the resample function in torchaudio and the source code here, which shows resampling with sinc interpolation.

You say you want sinc interpolation as if applying IFFT, zero-padding, and FFT. But then you say you can't do that "to convert the k-space to a spatial domain image it is not just a simple IFFT". These statements are orthogonal. You can do IFFT/pad/FFT, that has nothing to do with obtaining a proper spatial domain image. It is just a trick to interpolate your data. You get the same results if you do FFT/pad/IFFT.

But then, IFFT/pad/FFT is a really bad way to interpolate, because of boundary effects and all the high frequencies you potentially insert when zero-padding. The results you want to get are likely not at all meaningful, the undulations are most likely artificial. When interpolating, the first thing you need to figure out is if your data is sampled according to Nyquist. If it is, you can use cubic spline or Lanczos interpolation and get a very good approximation of the continuous function you sampled. If not, no interpolation method exists that can recover what you already lost.

The resample function of TorchAudio  is a very good starting point, sadly it still does not provide the same result as the FFT method. I looked at the source code and adapted it to accept complex numbers and interpolate the phase too.
This still does not explain why does sinc interpolation does not provide the same result as zero-padding when multiple sources say they should.

@CrisLuengo the undulations are a direct consequence of using Sinc.  Sinc filters have a band limit, and the limit causes ringing in the output.  I don't understand enough about the zero-padding theorem to say why they wouldn't be identical.

@MarkRansom But there's also the issue of the periodic boundary condition when doing things through the FFT. A lot of that ringing likely comes from the jump at the edges. Sinc filters have a band limit, but they don't have a limit in the temporal/spatial domain, so you cannot completely avoid the boundary effect. Lanczos is a windowed sinc filter, a much better choice for interpolation.
